# Increase tomcat Initial and Maximum memory pool in Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat9

How to increase my jvm memory for tomcat like windows.

[image]

Initial memory pool & Maximum memory pool.
For your information, I am using java 1.8 and tomcat 9.0.27.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to increase the JVM memory allocation and thread stack size in the Tomcat configuration tool , for this , add to the java options section:

```
-Xms<sizeinmb>m  -Xmx<sizeinmb>m options
```

for example:

```
-Xms1024m  -Xmx2048m
```

-Xms: It is used for setting the initial and minimum heap size. It is recommended to set the minimum heap size equivalent to the maximum heap size in order to minimize the garbage collection.

-Xmx: It is used for setting the maximum heap size. The performance will decrease if the max heap value is set lower than the amount of live data. It will force frequent garbage collections in order to free up space.

Comment: How to check exist Xms & Xmx ? And where does it located ? Please tips me to set Xms & Xmx in command lines.